# How do you use LEFT on a NTEXT SQL Server Column?

Tags: sql-server

How do you use the LEFT function (or an equivalent) on a SQL Server NTEXT column?

Basically I'm building a GridView and I just want to return the first 100 or so characters from the Description column which is NTEXT.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SELECT CAST(ntext_col AS nvarchar(100)) as ntext_substr FROM ...

[EDIT] Originally had it returning LEFT(N,100) of CAST to nvarchar(MAX), CASTing will truncate and since LEFT is wanted, that is enough.

Comment: I'd think that casting it as a NVARCHAR(100) would be enough, right?  If the cast works, then the value should already be the left 100 chars.

Comment: thanks worked fine. is there any reason it doesn't just work without the cast?

Comment: Updated to just do the CAST.  LEFT will not work on NTEXT, but CAST will truncate if longer than the length specified.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [SUBSTRING function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which "returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression":

```
SUBSTRING ( value_expression , start_expression , length_expression )
```

So, to select the first 100 characters from your `Description` NTEXT column, you would use something like the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Description, 1, 100) as truncatedDescription FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 5):

You would have to cast it to a VARCHAR(MAX) first.